# Scraping an API

Tags: python, json, database, scrapy, web-crawler

Good morning everyone,

I try to collect data about cars on this site: https://www.caramigo.eu/

To do so I need to launch a request on the search bar of the home page for a specified location and date. This provides me a page like this: https://www.caramigo.eu/be/fr/recherche?address=Belgique%2C+Wallonie%2C+Li%C3%A8ge%2C+4000%2C+Li%C3%A8ge&date_debut=22-03-2019&date_fin=23-03-2019

Then I can recover the data on a JSON file thanks to the developer tool of my web browser and scrape it. The issue is that the JSON file changes each time I launch a request for a new location and is located at the same URL (https://www.caramigo.eu/services/car).

Does anybody has an idea on how I can create a spider which will launch a request, get the JSON file, and scrape it ? Or maybe on how I can change the data on the API directly to get other locations ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What would be your inputs? Do you have a specific location you want to scrape data for, or do you want to get all the data?

Comment: Well I would like data about the characteristics of the car, the price for the rent, ... And I would like to scrape for all city centers of my country, there are approximatively 500 official cities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy filters requests to URLs already visited, to avoid loops. Since the resource you need uses the same URL always, Scrapy will filter that.

But you can disable it by using `dont_filter=True` in the request. Eg.:

```py
yield scrapy.Request(
   url='https://www.caramigo.eu/services/car',
   dont_filter=True,
   callback=self.parse_item
)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I still have an issue but It's maybe not in the scope of this question. Since my data is stored at the same adress, how can I use Scrapy to send a Request for changing the Page ? I mean, if I launch a search for New York, https://www.caramigo.eu/services/car will show information about New York cars, and it changes for each city. How can I do that with Scrapy ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: idk. You have to figure out how the site works. If it is stored in the server (aka stateful), you will have to request the search page for every city and use a [`cookiejar`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-cookiejar) to manage the session.